# Reporting system for mysql php web development

Tags: php, mysql, reporting-services

I have done most of my web development stuff with php/mysql in linux based server. Its been running fine as of now. I need an effective reporting system for taking reports directly from mysql (say 'crystal report' with mssql in windows server)

Is there any opensource reporting module stuff out in the market to interface it with mysql or otherwise can I make use of this crystal report itself but in linux server

Please suggest...

Answer (score 2):

Check out JasperReports.  http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you could create an ODBC connector on a windows machine that connects to your Linux server's MySQL, and then run Crystal Reports on that windows machine.